# fastcgi.logging is not set to 0 in php.ini file

Tags: php

i installed php in my OS (windows 7, 32-bit, IIS server),while installing i renamed the php.ini-production file to `php.ini` and uncomment the following lines in php.ini

```
fastcgi.impersonate =1

cgi.fix_pathinfo=1

cgi.force_redirect=0

fastcgi.logging=0
```

Then i add the handle mapping in default web site  in inetmgr and add the path in environment variables

then i restart the server..

when i run the program changes are not applying, my php  program is

```
phpinfo();
```

(sorry php syntax not showing)

please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my question..

first open the php.ini-production file and uncomment the

fastcgi.impersonate=1

cgi.fix_pathinfo=1

set cgi.force_redirect=0 and uncomment it

set fastcgi.logging=0 and uncomment it

then

rename php.ini-production to php.ini and save it to C:\windows

then run the phpinfo();

ur changes will appear there...

thank you...